# ABCPDF cutting off image

Tags: image, abcpdf

I had a problem with ABCPDF not rendering my image in PDF from the HTML I had. I was able to get an image to partially render by setting height/width properties on the image element. Now the problem is that the image is not showing in PDF as full. Rather it's showing up as a thin long line which is equal to it's height but the width is only 3 px. The image height/width were 380/680. I have set Render delay of 3000 in my code to facilitate loading of image completely but that didn't help either.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: What was the code for the render delay?

Comment: check this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028131/abcpdf-doesnt-render-images-in-an-web-application-under-iis6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. The problem wasn't with my code or height/width settings. Rather, it was the browser engine that ABCPDF uses by default - MSHTML. I set the engine to be Gecko and it all worked. You need to add this to your code

doc.HtmlOptions.Engine = EngineType.Gecko;

Good luck programming!